# jdownloader2 import txt files with links (regex)

Tags: regex, jdownloader

maybe some people know jdownloader2. its a download manager.
regex is also used with the download manager.
so i want to tell you what i basically try to do: i have multiple txt files with many links. all text files have file names, of course.
i would like to drag and drop all text files into jdownloader2, so it decrypts the txt files and adds each text file to a package. the package name shall be the txt files name.
what i found so for is this:

```
[ {
  "enabled" : true,
  "maxDecryptDepth" : 2,
  "name" : null,
  "pattern" : "file:/.*?\\.txt$",
  "rule" : "DEEPDECRYPT",
  "packageNamePattern" : null,
  "formPattern" : null,
  "deepPattern" : null,
  "rewriteReplaceWith" : null
} ]
```

this makes jdownloader to crawl the links from a txt file. but the problem is: it gives every single file in the links an own name, because packagenamepattern has noe definiton. so it uses the original file names in the links to make packages. so if i have a txt file with 100 links, it will make 100 packages with different names. 
but i want it to read the 100 links in the txt file and put them all in one package.
so.. how do i need to change "packagenamepattern" to make jdownloader2 put all 100 links from a text file into one package, and the package name should be the textfiles name. it has something to do with regex, i think (i hope im not wrong with my thinking)

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Asuming it works for finding the text files with the partern, you can add the pattern as string for the packagename, instead of null.
I didn't understood quite for what stands each variable exactly:
"name" : null,
"pattern" : "file:/.*?\.txt$",
"rule" : "DEEPDECRYPT",

`String regex_package_name = "\\.*\.txt"  /*is where you define your regexcode to locate filename  starting with last "\(for windows, or "/" for Linux)  until end of the filename (".txt").*/`

I tested it myself an it works (on [regex_tester](https://www.regextester.com/?fam=129794))

The problem that you have is that for each matcher found, an index will be incremented and so will be added a new file for each link. You have to introduce a while loop that goes trough all the file first with  a break condition when reaching the last char.
Also there should not be nulls for the other values if you want to define a packagename ("packageNamePattern","formPattern","deepPattern")

If this doesn't work, you have to implement yourselve a method that reads all the links from 1 file and stores them in another file (.txt or .java) with the name of the file.
This is how much I can help.

Have a nice day ;-)